# VS2015 + Xamarin freeze, endlessly editing Xamarin log

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I noticed when developing for Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 it tends to sometimes randomly freeze when in code editor with 'VS is busy' message. This time I decided to check Process Monitor and found out that all it does is open Xamarin log, edit it, close it, repeat. Is it possible to disable this logging, or something?

[image: Part of Process Monitor output, there're about 20k lines of this]

Comment: Check on the Task Manager if the memory go increasing until stack overflow. (Deadlock). And are you using Windows 10?

Comment: What do the Xamarin logs say? (Also, please consider filing this as a bug for the Xamarin team: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Visual%20Studio%20Extensions)